# The MAC signature found in the HTTP request is not same as computed from azure server

Tags: azure, postman

I am trying to hit Azure blob service from POST man. I have the Azure account name, sharedKey which we are using from java code to hit Azure media services.

I had read through the Azure documentation for the reference but it's not working when I hit from POST man though I passed all the required credentials like 'Azure accountName, shared key', please find the below details which I am using from Postman.

> URL - https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/yyy/myblob
>   (Note:xxx- accountName, yyy- container)
>   header:
>   x-ms-date: value
>   x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
>   x-ms-version: 2017-11-09
>   Authorization: SharedKey xxx:hascodeKey (which we are using for media service which is working one)

I want to know, is the shared key same for Azure media service and Azure blob service?

Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authenticate-with-shared-key on how to generate authorization header. You can't use the key as is.